# Why did Karin keep the umbilical cord, if she's not Sarada's mother?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

I'm just very confused about this situation.Why did Karin keep the umbilical cord, if she's not Sarada's mother?Anyone explain it.

Comment: yeah, that's weird, it's unusual  for keep it with her. May be because of Uchiha blood ( for some crazy experiment with Orochimaru ) or Her fantasy for Sasuke. :D ) Just a guess ;)

Comment: do we have any evidence that she is not her mother ? because i believe she is

Comment: Maybe Sarada was the first baby she delivered so she wanted to remember that by keeping the cord.

Comment: @Nevios In the manga it is confirmed that the umbilical cord is of Sakura. Karin had preserved it. The alleged confusion that 'Karin is Sarada's mother' arised because when Suigetsu matched Sarada's DNA with the umbilical cord, it showed a match. (Suigetsu thought that the umbilical cord is of Karin)

Answer (score 2):

Karin kept the umbilical cord as a memento of her help during Sarada's birth. Canonically being the one who offered assistance to Sakura while Sakura was in labor and the one who contributed to Sarada's delivery, Karin was very helpful to the Uchiha family back then. Through her actions, she formed a bond with them, and the umbilical cord basically serves as a reminder of that exact connection.

**By the way, Sarada's parentage indeed isn't debatable anymore.**

Her true parentage was already officially confirmed, and this happened for the first time all the way back in 2015 in the manga called *"Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring"*. Following this, the confirmations from the manga were animated in the anime *"Boruto: Naruto Next Generations"*, and after this they were even strengthened in many other episodes.

Below, there are all the canon panels/moments that serve as confirmations about Sarada's real parentage.

**The confirmations offered by Sakura:**

- In the manga (*"Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring"*, chapter 10):

[image]

- In the anime (first confirmation - *"Boruto: Naruto Next Generations"*, episode 23):

[image]

- Also in the anime (a whole lot more confirmations - *"Boruto: Naruto Next Generations"*, episodes 170 and 171):

[image]

**The confirmation offered by Sasuke:**

- In the manga (*"Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring"*, chapter 10):

[image]

- In the anime (*"Boruto: Naruto Next Generations"*, episode 23):

[image]

**The confirmations offered by Karin:**

- In the manga (*"Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring"*, chapter 10):

[image]

- In the anime (first confirmation - *"Boruto: Naruto Next Generations"*, episode 23):

[image]

- In the anime (once again, a whole lot more confirmations - *"Boruto: Naruto Next Generations"*, episodes 101 and 102):

[image]

So, everyone needs to learn the **difference** between the aspects of a story that can be theorized on and the ones that straightforwardly can't. **When something has already been canonically established, there is absolutely no point in making any new *theories* about that very same fact since it simply can't be altered.**

**Sakura was established as the canon biological mother of Sarada, and that's the end of the matter.**

Answer (score 0):

A hypothesis is for this question is that sasuke took in too much of Karin's chakra when healing himself. You can obviously hear her say on the episode of capturing the eight-tails"He took in too much chakra". We know that chakra may influence living beings, so it is possible that Karin's chakra may affect Sasuke's child. Or because Karin helped deliver Sakura and Sasuke's baby, so she might've just kept it. (We know how obsessed Karin can be with something.)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but new people will see. I consider myself very in tune with Naruto/Boruto. The simple fact is this. Karin is Sarada’s Mom or she carried her(surrogate) because Sakura could not. Why would they dedicate a whole arc about this? They talked about DNA and bonds. The big thing is Karin kept the cord.  The whole Boruto show is about making new life or changing it in some sort of way. Sorry I got side tracked. So back to Sarada. Boruto mirrors Naruto in many ways. The creator has stated Sarada will play a major role. Sarada will redeem the Uchiha and become Hokage like Madara should have been. Sasuke is still a rouge (kinda) he left Sarada to Sakura and Naruto because she would be safe in the Leaf. She is the only Uchiha beside Sasuke. People will be after them. Otkusuki. Sasuke can’t protect her out in the world by himself. So either Karin and Sasuke trusted The Leaf and Naruto to keep her safe or Karin carries her for Sakura.